# How to run VSCode in a docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, home-assistant

How can I run vscode in a docker container so I can open the UI in a web browser? I know it is possible because home-assistant can do it. It can only do it when hosted on a raspberry pi, not in a separate docker container or other home-assistant installs. All the results I found online point at developing apps for executing in docker - in vscode that's running on your local machine. That's not what I want, I want to have a local vscode install hosted on my local server - that way I can set up my dev environment in one place and don't have to keep setting everything up on all of my machines.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's officially possible to [self-host vscode server and access it through vscode.dev](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) (also see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135856)).

For reaching it through custom URL consider using [Gitpod's OpenVSCode Server](https://github.com/gitpod-io/openvscode-server) fork of vscode.

If you just want to share your configuration between machines, it's probably simplest to just use [settings sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync), which is available in default installation.